# Beamercolortheme: How to set default color for all verbatim?

Tags: beamer, color, verbatim

I want to change the color of *all* verbatim text in an existing beamer presentation. How do I do this easily?

I know how to use colored verbatim text in general, and I found a lot of suggestions here either for defining colored verbatim environments, but this does not help me: the existing presentation uses plain `\verb` and `verbatim`- and `semiverbatim`-envrionments. It does not use `fancyvrb` or such. I do not want to go through the entire presentation (a whole lecture) and change every single verbatim command, just to change the color of the presented code fragments.

I would simply like verbatim text to have a different color, just like all math can be defined to have a different color to mark that it is math.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine `\verbatim@font`. E.g.

```
\makeatletter 
  \renewcommand\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\color{blue}}
\makeatother
```